# Aplicación que no da ningún error pero no presenta ningún widget

Tags: python-3.x

Con gran trabajo y ayuda he eliminado todos los errores que se me presentaban en una aplicación de Python con QtDesigner, todo perfecto. Depuro todos los módulos y todo va sin ningún problema ni error, pero... no me aparece ninguno de los widgets. El módulo de entrada es un login. Lo que tengo es en login.py:

```py
import sys

import os

myDir = os.get.getcwd()

sys.path.append(myDir)

from LoginController import LoginController

from principal import Ui_Principal

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Login(objet):

   def __init__(self)

      self.login_controller=LoginController(self)

   def setupUi(self, Login):
       
      (aquí toda la GUI)

   def retranslateUi(self, LogIn):
 
     _translate= QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

     LogIn.setWindowTitle(_translate("LogIn", "MainWindow")

     self.label.setText(_translate("LogIn", "Iniciar Sesión")

     self.label_2.setText(_translate("Login","Usuario":")) 

     self.input_user.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Login", "contraseña"))

     self.input_password.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Login", "contraseña"))

     self.btn_login.setText(_translate("Login", "entrar"))
     
     if __name__=="__main__":
          import sys
          app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
          LogIn=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
          ui=Ui_LogIn()    
          ui.setupUi(LogIn)
          LogIn.show()
          sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Yo uso PySide2, pero ambos son bindings del modulo Qt de C++ (si no me equivoco).  Sin ver un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) me es casi imposible saber la causa. Asi que voy a adivinar. Ubicaste tus widgets en un layout y estableciste dicho en un QWidget y a ese QWidget lo pusiste como widget central de la ventana? Ese detalle es importante.

Comment: Aparte del comentario de @FranciscoJavier, veo que hay problemas con las comillas, no sé si fue error al crear la pregunta o si así tienes el código pero por ejemplo, en esta línea tienes unas comillas de más `self.label_2.setText(_translate("Login","Usuario":"))`

Comment: Los errores mecanográficos, han sido cosa de tecleo, En el programa lo tenía bien. No puedo aportar ningún emcy porque todos los debug pasan sin problema. El consejo sobre ubicación de los widgets dentro de layout etc no lo entiendo bien. Traigo aquí el texto de la sección GUI de la class Ui_LogIn(object) del módulo login.py, que omití antes. Es larguísimom, pero si stack overflor  me lo permite y tenéis paciencia para mirarla, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si os encontráis con ánimos para sacarme del atolladero mediante ujna retribución, podríamos llegar a un acuerdo.

Comment: Parece haber problemas con la indentación. El último `if __name__ =="__main__"` debe ir a primer nivel, creo.

Comment: Candid Moe, tienes razón, pero es un error de transcripción; en el script está bien puesto, en primer nivel.

Comment: Te doy una idea de como podrias dar un emcv: en setupUi muestra de que modo intentas crear un solo widget (uno solo) y no se ubica. Tiene que suceder que yo ejecute tu código en mi pc y ocurra el mismo error.

Comment: Un emcv NO tiene por que ser tu código original.